# How to randomly output one of two strings?

Tags: c++, string

If I have two strings, how would I randomly choose between the two?

For example if I had

```
int main() {
  string m;
  string n;
  cin>>m;
  cin>>n;
  return 0;
}
```

how would I make a generator that randomly outputs `m` or `n`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [rand()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/) as follows:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
int main(){
    srand(time(0));         //-- initializes random seed
    int x = rand() % 2;     //-- generate random integer between 0 and 1
    if(x == 0) cout<<m;
    else cout<<n;
}
```